# angularjs business logic

Tags: angularjs

In Angularjs it is possible to use a restful server api just to store the objects with all the business logic embedded in Javascript.  Most of the examples seems to point in that direction.

Is this not bad practice both in terms of maintainability and security?

Comment: question is far too vague... if you want reasonable responses need to be more specifc about concerns

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question *is* a little vague, but I'll try to give a broad answer: I do not feel it is bad practice to migrate logic to the client side.

**Maintainability**

Heavens no! I started my career on the backend and I can say with a high degree of confidence that whether the code is on the front or on the back has no weight on its maintainability; code is code. Whether we place it in a reusable service component on the client or a reusable library on the server, change management is very similar. See the security section for an important additional note.

**Business Logic**

Honestly, I've never understood why developers are so reticent when it comes to their business logic. It's as if in their minds if only someone were to reverse engineer their code, they would discover some magical reality of which they had never conceived - they would be witness to the developer's genius! - and would now be sufficiently armed to commit some act of market aggression.

This is absurd. They can see your service; they can see your user interface; they know the goal. If they want to replicate you, they already can. It's *incredibly* rare that it is our business logic that is the key to our products. It's just not a concern in 99% of cases.

And any massively complex algorithm at the center of business wouldn't end up on the client anyway, right? We do the heavily lifting on our distributed file stores with map/reduce operations and semantic graphs...

**Security**

This is an important consideration as always, but the key is in the REST API. The REST API is the official gateway that cannot be tampered with. If our `user` model requires a `first_name` field, it is the REST API's job to ensure that field is there. We probably also introduce checks on the client-side, but these are almost always created with user experience in mind: synchronous and instant feedback is better than asynchronous and delayed feedback.

Anything related to security, strictly defined, is on the server. Authentication and authorization are obviously on the server. They're never on the client. So we're not introducing any vulnerabilities by choosing the single-page application paradigm. Just think about Twitter, or Google products, or Facebook - they all have open APIs that we can use in lieu of the web interface to accomplish the same goals. The APIs enforce the key rules, they ensure proper security, but they leave user experience up to the client.

Obviously, this implies that *some* logic is duplicated on the client and server, like basic validation. Sure. But we do it for user experience. It introduces a little bit more complexity into our change management processes, but it's *far outweighed* by the user experience gains.

Comment: what about maintainability in terms of potentially running out of date code because user has not refreshed?

Comment: Like they leave the website open for days on end without interruption? Is that an important feature in most apps? In either event, if the API changes, it should be versioned the same way as for any client application.